# how to remove wrapper div in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

could you please tell me how to remove wrapper div in react js ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-oskar-nbwjs?file=/src/App.js

**current output**

```
 <div id="root">
   <div class="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
         <section>ddddd</section>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Expected output**

```
<div id="root">
       <div class="App">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
             <section>ddddd</section>
       </div>
    </div>
```

how to remove this wrapper `div`.       `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48236588/using-fragment-to-insert-html-rendered-on-the-back-end-via-dangerouslysetinnerht

Answer (score 1):

I do want to disclaim any knowledge of your app's full context and could be looking at it wrong, but I want to offer a more fundamental solution. Why not simply do it like this?

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const Elem = () => <section>ddddd</section>

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Elem />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This would certainly remove that wrapper, but again, there may be something I don't know about the app.

Answer (score 0):

use `<React.Fragment><React.Fragment/>` instead of div this will work

Comment: Fragments don’t support this.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12014
This is a very long going question, but as per the issue, it's not resolved yet

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple like:

```
<div className="App">
    <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    { createMarkup() }
</div>
```

And change the function:

```
function createMarkup() {
    return <section>ddddd</section>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to do this:

```
    import Parser from 'html-react-parser';
        <div>
            {Parser('<div>
                 <section>ddddd</section>
              </div>', {
                replace: (domNode) => {
                    if (domNode.name === 'div') {
                        return <section>ddddd</section>;
                    }
                }
            })}
        </div>
```